# i got an error while calling non abstract method via child class

Tags: c#-4.0

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
    // in here iam create an instance of child class
            var obj = new dog("meat");
            obj.run();
            obj.sleep();

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
    abstract class animal {
        protected string eating;
        abstract public void sound();

        public void run() {
            Console.WriteLine("Runnig");
        }
        public void sleep()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("sleeping");
        }
    }
    class cat : animal
    {
        public cat(string eat) {
            this.eating = eat;
        }
// this is my child class define parent class method
        protected override void sound()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Meow");

        }
    }
    class dog : animal{

        public dog(string eat){
            this.eating = eat;
        }
        public override void sound()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Woof");

        }
    }
```

// Error : Error    1   'Abbstraction.cat.sound()': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'public' inherited member 'Abbstraction.animal.sound()'  E:\C sharp\ObjectOrientedConcept\Abbstraction\Program.cs    39  33  Abbstraction

Answer (score 1):

You define the abstract method signature `sound()` in the `abstract class Animal` as public.

Later you try to change the access modifier to protected. This is not allowed. You have to stick to the modifier defined in the base class.